# Redirecting On a Schedule with Whenever Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

I'm trying to use the `Whenever` gem to make a page appear every five minutes, but to no avail. I installed the gem using the steps found on the [Github page](https://github.com/javan/whenever) and I have the following in my `schedule.rb` file:

```
every 5.minutes do
  redirect_to new_man_test_path
end
```

I get no errors, but the page has also not appeared (I tried `every 5.seconds do` as well, so I know it's not a problem with my patience or counting).  Any help or ideas to get this to work?

Comment: whenever is tied to cron on the host system, which won't even have an interactive terminal attached, much less a web browser.  Where would you like the results of "new_man_test_path" to be displayed?  To all users at a particular path?  Is this a caching situation?

Comment: @JimVanFleet I'm actually just trying to redirect any user to that page every 5 minutes. I'm new to cron jobs, so I'm struggling.

Comment: so, any user is browsing the site, clicking pages/links, etc. and every five minutes, you'd like them to go to a specific page on the site?

Comment: @JimVanFleet As irritating as that sounds, yes. It would also work as a popup (and would possibly be better) but I didn't want to bite off more than I could chew....

Comment: cron won't work for this since it doesn't even know humans are hitting the site.  cron itself doesn't even know Rails is running on the box.  You'll need the app to manage time via the session (or a cookie) and react with redirects on the Rails side (can only work on a full page load) or URL redirecting on the JavaScript there (could work any time, complex to pull off).

Comment: @JimVanFleet, that makes sense. How would I go about structuring a Rails redirect based on session time?

Comment: that's so far removed from this question, I suggest refiling it.  (Feel free to mention me in a comment after you post it.)